# C# Get custom number format from standard format

Tags: c#, number-formatting, cultureinfo

I need to get the custom format from a standard format as defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

E.g.
"D6" => "000000"

For DateTime values there is `cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(char)`.

Is there something equivalent for numbers?

Comment: I need to write it to a localized Excel file and Excel does not support these standard format strings.

Comment: I cannot avoid standard format strings, as I need them to be culture aware: en Culture + N2 => [$-en]#,##0.00 - de CUlture + N2 => [$-de]#.##0,00 and excel does not support using a culture aware thousands separator and decimal sign based on a fixed culture. Excel does only support culture aware separators based on the culture that is used for the Excel that is opening the spreadsheet.